# Can I create a Jump table in VBA for Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, jump-table

I wrote a simple translator / parser to process an EDI (830) document using multiple `Select Case` statements to determine the code to be executed. I’m opening a file in binary mode and splitting the document into individual lines, then each line is split into the various elements where the first element of every line has a unique segment identifier.

My code works perfectly as written. However, `Select Case` requires checking every `Case` until a match is found or the `Case Else` is executed.  I’ve sequenced the `Case` statements in such a manner that the segments that appear most frequently (as in the case of loops), are placed first to minimize the number of "checks before code is actually executed.

Rather than using multiple `Select Case`s, I would prefer to determine an index for the segment identifier and simply call the appropriate routine using that index.  I’ve used jump tables in C and Assembler and anticipated similar functionality may be possible in VBA.

Comment: Help us to help you; **post your current code.**

Comment: You can use a dictionary to directly access a value via a key: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dictionary-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do jump tables in VBA by using the `Application.Run` method to call the appropriate routine by name. The following code demonstrates how it works:

```
Public Sub JumpTableDemo()

  Dim avarIdentifiers() As Variant
  avarIdentifiers = Array("Segment1", "Segment2")
  Dim varIdentifier As Variant
  For Each varIdentifier In avarIdentifiers
    Run "Do_" & varIdentifier
  Next varIdentifier

End Sub

Public Sub Do_Segment1()
  Debug.Print "Segment1"
End Sub

Public Sub Do_Segment2()
  Debug.Print "Segment2"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Excel VBA, following the example below:

[image]

The example assumes you have split your EDI document into two columns, one with the 'processing instruction' and one with the data that instruction will process.

The jump table is to the right i.e. a distinct list of the 'processing instructions' plus a name of a `Sub`-routine to run for each instruction.

The code is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub JumpTable()

    Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range '<-- data from your file
    Dim rngCell As Range '<-- current "instruction"
    Dim rngJump As Range '<-- table of values and sub to run for value
    Dim strJumpSub As String
    Dim strJumpData As String

    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction '<-- just a coding shortcut

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- change to your worksheet
    Set rngData = ws.Range("A2:A17") '<-- change to your range
    Set rngJump = ws.Range("E2:F4") '<-- change to your circumstances

    For Each rngCell In rngData
        strJumpSub = wsf.VLookup(rngCell.Value, rngJump, 2, False) '<-- lookup the sub
        strJumpData = rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value '<-- get the data
        Application.Run strJumpSub, strJumpData '<-- call the sub with the data
    Next rngCell

End Sub

Sub do_foo(strData As String)
    Debug.Print strData
End Sub

Sub do_bar(strData As String)
    Debug.Print strData
End Sub

Sub do_baz(strData As String)
    Debug.Print strData
End Sub
```

Make sure that you have written a `Sub` for each entry in the jump table.